Troubleshooting AWS Secrets Manager Access Problems in EKS Node Group
You have an Amazon EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service) cluster with a node group consisting of two EC2 instances (nodes). Both nodes are part of the same node group and should have identical configurations. You are using AWS Secrets Manager to securely store and manage secrets, which you need to access from your applications running on the EKS cluster.

Problem: One of the nodes is able to pull secrets from AWS Secrets Manager successfully, while the other node is encountering errors when trying to access these secrets.
I0829 04:57:10.874010       1 auth.go:123] Role ARN for dev-ns:sm-sa is arn:aws:iam::91xxxxxx0031:role/aws-eks-oidc-role
W0829 04:58:45.144719       1 secrets_manager_provider.go:84] ap-south-1: Failed fetching secret eks-ssm-dev: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials
caused by: RequestError: send request failed


Verify IAM Role and Permissions

Iamrole : aws-eks-oidc-role
Policy Check: Ensure that the IAM policy attached to the role includes permissions like secretsmanager:GetSecretValue and secretsmanager:DescribeSecret for the specific secret ARN.
**try with ** - Secrets Manager (Full access)
Trusted entities
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::91xxxxxx0031:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/id/3FFF1AB9xxxxx304xxxxxF74F5F"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/id/3FFF1AB9xxxxx304xxxxxF74F5F:sub": [
                        "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:aws-load-balancer-controller",
                        "system:serviceaccount:dev-ns:sm-sa"
                    ],
                    "oidc.eks.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/id/3FFF1AB9xxxxx304xxxxxF74F5F:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

service account
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sm-sa
  namespace: dev-ns
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::91xxxxxx0031:role/aws-eks-oidc-role


Secrets Manager CSI driver Deployment
helm repo add secrets-store-csi-driver https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver/charts
helm install csi-secrets-store secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver --namespace kube-system --set syncSecret.enabled=true --set enableSecretRotation=true

Secrets Manager CSI driver Provider Deployment
helm repo add aws-secrets-manager https://aws.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws
helm install -n kube-system secrets-provider-aws aws-secrets-manager/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws



Deployment YAML file sample file
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-deployment
  namespace: dev-ns
spec:
  replicas: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example-app
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: sm-sa
      volumes:
      - name: secrets-store-inline
        csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: "example-secret-provider" 
      containers:
      - name: example-container
        image: your-docker-image:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets-store-inline
          mountPath: /mnt/secrets
          readOnly: true
        env:
        - name: MY_SECRET_KEY1
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: example-secret
              key: my-secret-data-key1
        - name: MY_SECRET_KEY2
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: example-secret
              key: my-secret-data-key2


SecretProviderClass YAML
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: example-secret-provider
  namespace: dev-ns
spec:
  provider: "aws"
  secretObjects:
    - secretName: example-secret
      type: "Opaque"
      data:
        - objectName: "my-secret-key1"
          key: "my-secret-data-key1"
        - objectName: "my-secret-key2"
          key: "my-secret-data-key2"
  parameters:
    objects: |
      - objectName: "my-aws-secret-name"
        objectType: "secretsmanager"
        jmesPath:
          - path: "my-secret-key1"
            objectAlias: "my-secret-data-key1"
          - path: "my-secret-key2"
            objectAlias: "my-secret-data-key2"


I have check with
kubectl top nodes


node1 pods are running...
node2 pods are not running..

If one node is working and the other is not, there could be a node-specific issue such as network configuration, IAM role attachment, or kubelet configuration
Verify that both nodes (EC2 instance) have the same instance profile attached. The instance profile should be linked to the IAM role (aws-eks-oidc-role).
If that not the issue recreate the node as there can an underlying issue with the node's kubelet or networking configuration

Thank you for your response it's help me
